# Why is onCreate() being called whenever I launch a new activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a fairly simple app that just display quotes.

I have some setup code in onCreate() that I wrote with the assumption that it would only be called once, but that seemingly isn't the case. I've ran into some bugs that turn out to be cause by the fact that every time a new activity is launched, my main activity's onCreate() function runs again.

I've Googled around and people claim that onCreate() should only be called once in the app's lifecycle, but I've added a Log.v in my onCreate and can clearly see it runs every time an activity is launched from it, which makes no sense. I've tried setting the launchMode to singleTop, my one activity ends with finish(), but that doesn't make a difference.

Edit: see my answer below. Turns out my other activities were extending my main activity, which was making the super methods be called multiple times. Don't do that!

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Maybe you are destroying it every time and creating again

Comment: I really don't know what all there is to post. The intent launches just look like:

Intent launchQuoteListIntent = new Intent(Quotr.this, QuoteListActivity.class);
startActivity(launchQuoteListIntent);

This is more of a general Android question as to why  onCreate() is called whenever an activity is launched. I don't know if this is specific to my app.

Comment: "onCreate() should only be called once in the app's lifecycle": this is not true. The `onCreate()` of an activity is called once for each instance of that activity class.

Comment: So I realized something. It actually isn't happening with all my activities that are launched. The one that I was testing it on (while watching the logcat to see when onCreate and onDestroy is being called) specifically was one that was actually launching with startActivityForResult(). The other ones don't have the issue, but the activity I call for a result does. When the activity is launched from the main activity, main's onCreate is called, and when the new activity is finished, main's onDestroy() is called, which I don't understand.

Comment: I've since been able to "fix" the issue by just changing some of the control flow (it was running some code multiple times in onCreate that I only wanted run when the activity is actually created, but I just added a check to see if it was already run). But still, it seems like a waste of resources to run onCreate every time this other activity is called when nothing actually needs to be destroyed/recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally solved it. I guess I'm a complete idiot, but when I first started this app a year and a half ago, I didn't really know what I was doing since it was my first app.

For some reason when I implemented the first new activity, I made it extend the main activity instead of AppCompatActivity. So my calls to super.onCreate() and super.onDestroy() in the new activity were calling its super class, which was main activity. That makes a ton of sense why I was having this issue now.

You can get surprisingly far into development with a mistake like this unnoticed, so maybe someone else will make this mistake in the future and be helped by this post.

Comment: Thank you, thank you and thank you Hayden. You extended the main activity because just like me you saw that in some tutorials. This also produces tons of hard to track bugs. I cannot understand how someone downvoted your answer.

Comment: @Gauthier glad I could help! Yeah I wouldn't be surprised if it was a tutorial that taught me to extend the main activity, cause I don't know where I would have got that idea from otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

check your

> onDestroy()

check if it's called

because on create is never called unless o

> nDestroy()

is called